# advanced css flex alignment and wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to align two spans inside a container in a very peculiar way. One span should be left justified the other right justified, like this:

```
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXX   YYYYYYYYY|
+---------------------+
```

but when it comes to an overlap, the right aligned text should be placed in an extra row.
Like this:

```
+--------------+
|XXXXXXXX      |
|       YYYYYYY|
+--------------+
```

The following code however aligns the second span to the left.

```
div {
  width: 40%; /* force narrow div to start with */
  display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;
}

<div>
  <span>left align some text</span>
  <span>right align some other text</span>
</div>
```

```
+-----------------------------+ /* yay */
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX     YYYYYYYYYY|
+-----------------------------+

+--------------------+ /* nope */
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX      |
|YYYYYYYYYY          |
+--------------------+
```

Leaving out flex wrap:

```
+--------------------+
|XXXXXXX       YYYYYY|
|XXXX            YYYY|
+--------------------+
```

I also tried

- Using float+clear but this resulted in a zero height container
- position: absolute; right: 0px which did not work relative to the container!

Is there a way to solve this without explicitly going though all my containers and computing everything via javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `justify-content` use `auto` margins.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
}

span:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>left align some text</span>
  <span>right align some other text</span>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/frcb6sop/)

[Understanding flex auto margins.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: Excactly what I needed! Thank you!